# Unexpected behaviour when drawing textbox controls C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am dynamically drawing TextBox controls based on data in an XML file to a Windows C# form but the resulting drawn textbox's have weird behaviour issues. I have tried doing this in a blank project and the same issue arises. The text in the TextBox control appears to be in weird positions and I dont have the ability to scroll through the text. I'm not sure what the issue is here.
My code:

```
private void DrawElements()
        {
            NameValueCollection DatabaseConnectionList = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("databaseTypes") as NameValueCollection;
            int x = 50;
            int y = 70;
            for (int i = 0; i < DatabaseConnectionList.Count; i++)
            {

                Label l = new Label();
                l.Text = "Prefix";
                l.Location = new Point(x, y);

                TextBox T = new TextBox();
                T.Text = DatabaseConnectionList.GetKey(i).ToString();
                T.Size = new Size(200, 20);
                T.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                x += 20;
                T.Location = new Point(x, y);

                Label l2 = new Label();
                l2.Text = "Connection String";
                x += 20 + 200;
                l2.Location = new Point(x, y);

                TextBox T2 = new TextBox();
                T2.Text = DatabaseConnectionList.Get(i).ToString();
                T2.Size = new Size(200, 20);
                T2.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                x += 20;
                T2.Location = new Point(x, y);

                this.Controls.Add(l);
                this.Controls.Add(T);
                this.Controls.Add(l2);
                this.Controls.Add(T2);
                y += 25;
                x = 50;
            }
            this.Refresh();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawElements();
        }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="databaseTypes" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="dataDictionary" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <databaseTypes>
    <add key="ExampleServerPrefix_T" value="Connection_String_For_ExampleServer" />
    <add key="ExampleServer2Prefix_T" value="Connection_String_For_ExampleServer_2" />
    <add key="COPYLIVE_" value="ODBC;DSN=blah;" />
  </databaseTypes>
</configuration>
```

The outputted form after clicking the button is always:
[image: he]

You can see that the text is chopped and in weird positions.

Comment: I see that you are creating TextBoxes. I don't see you _drawing_ them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with the length of the labels, instead of the position of the textboxes.

I suggest to use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is the easiest control to use for this kind of layouts.

Comment: It was an issue with the label but I will use the `TableLayoutPanel` instead as this seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Ben: I know it was the label (it is even in the answer). Have been there myself. :)